# Strict serializability example clarification?

Tags: distributed-system, distributed-transactions, consistency

I am trying to learn the different consistency models and I ran into [these slides](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall18/cos418/docs/p8-consistency.pdf).  However, I can't interpret the slide below on strict serializability which slide 4 of the slides says that **a read sees the latest write**.

- Does `W(x)b` mean `write b in x`?
- Is the order of transactions
  moving from left to right? If so, why would `P3` in the strictly
  serializable example `read a from x` (if the assumption in the
  previous bullet point above is correct),  if `P1` had already
  `written b in x`?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

> Does W(x)b mean write b in x?

It appears to be the other way around, i.e. Write x to b. So the operations are

1. Write x to a
2. Write x to b
3. Write y to b
4. Read x from a
5. Read x from b
6. Read y from b

> Is the order of transactions moving from left to right? If so, why
> would...

Yes. If we assume the 4 time slices to be say t1 through t4, we see that in the second example, at time t3, the processes are trying to *simultaneously* write and read y from b (i.e. operations 3 and 6). This is not strictly serializable because you can get two different values depending on which operation you order first when you try to serialize the operations.